# CHANGE the size of a rectangle?

Tags: c#, resize, rectangles

I need to change the size of a rectangle when something happens.  This is C#

```
        if (face1.Y > 440)
        {
            rndLocation();
            //rectangle size changes
        }
```

Comment: So what are you asking really?

Comment: @Muctadir I used .Inflate() to increase the size of a rectangle but I'd like to reset it's size. I was wondering how.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new rectangle of the size you want it to be.

Or just set the `Height` or `Width` properties of the rectangle.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rectangle, all you have to do is do `Rectangle.Width += sizeVar`/`Rectangle.Width += sizeVar`. Use the [rectangle struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to accomplish this.